# windows script host error (Error Code 8007202f)

Tags: excel, vbscript, active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

An error occurred while using a custom VBScript to create users in active directory users and computers in windows server 2012.

> Error Code 8007202f, a Constraint Violation occurred

The `.vbs` file retrieves data from an Excel file. I used the script to create user accounts once, but when the script was used again for the second time, the error occurred.

[image]

Here is the script I used:

```
'On Error Resume Next
'Make sure to change the OU name as appropriate. Watch about the space after the name.
'Change the domain name also



strOU = "OU=TempOU ," 
strSheet = "C:\staff.xls"
'strPWD = "12345678"
' Bind to Active Directory, Users container.
Set objRootLDAP = GetObject("LDAP://rootDSE")
Set objContainer = GetObject("LDAP://" & strOU & _
objRootLDAP.Get("defaultNamingContext"))

' Open the Excel spreadsheet
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objSpread = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strSheet)
intRow = 2 'Skip row for headings


Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
   strCN = Trim(objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value)
   strFirst = Trim(objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value)
   strSam = Trim(objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value)
   strDscpt = Trim(objExcel.Cells(intRow, 4).Value)
   strLast = Trim(objExcel.Cells(intRow, 5).Value)
   strpasswd=Trim(objExcel.Cells(intRow, 6).Value)
   'strpasswd=""




'Principal Name
strPrin =  strSam & "@" & "NSBMTEST.com"
'New Container Name and display
strCNnew = strCN


 'Created container name as SMB_
  Set objUser = objContainer.Create("User", "cn=" & strCNnew)


   objUser.userPrincipalName = strPrin
   objUser.sAMAccountName = strSam
   objUser.givenName = strFirst
   'objUser.sn = strLast
   objUser.displayName = strCNnew
   objUser.Description = strDscpt   
   objUser.SetInfo

   ' enable account with password
   objUser.userAccountControl = 512
   objUser.pwdLastSet = 0
   objUser.SetPassword strPWD
   objUser.SetPassword strpasswd
   objUser.SetInfo

    'Pw set to not expire
    'Const ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = &H10000
    'lngFlag = objUser.userAccountControl
   ' lngFlag = lngFlag Or ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD
    'objUser.userAccountControl = lngFlag
    'objUser.SetInfo

intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Quit
WScript.Quit
```

Comment: You're trying to do something that AD doesn't want you to do. Please indicat in which line exactly the error occurs. Also, why are you setting the user password twice (with `strPWD` and `strpasswd`)?

Comment: But the provided code snippet contains only  **43** lines.

Comment: I edited your code to make it more readable by removing all useless comments and improving the formatting. Instead of reverting that you could've just indicated that the error occurs in the `objUser.SetInfo` line.

Comment: ok thanks for a editing :) if you can edit it again :)